# Programmatically installing unsigned driver with CreateService

Tags: windows, winapi, driver

I am trying to install an unsigned driver that I got from an older embedded solution (winxp embedded), that I am currently reversing. I am installing and setting up the driver like the software does, however, with the driver being unsigned, I am unable to install it, at least programmatically.

Installation code:

```
std::cout << "Installing driver from " << this->driverPath << std::endl;

SC_HANDLE scManager = OpenSCManagerA(0, 0, 0xF003F);
if (!scManager) {
    std::cout << "Failed to open SCManager" << std::endl;
    return;
}
SC_HANDLE hService = CreateServiceA(scManager, this->serviceName, this->serviceName, 0xF01FF, 1, 3, 1, this->driverPath, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
if (!hService) {
    hService = OpenServiceA(scManager, this->serviceName, 0xF01FF);
    if (!hService) {
        std::cout << "error: " << std::to_string(GetLastError()) << std::endl;
        CloseServiceHandle(scManager);
        return;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "OK!" << std::endl;
    }
}

if (!StartServiceA(hService, 0, 0)) {
    std::cout << "StartService failed: " << std::to_string(GetLastError()) << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

The command line output based on this is as follows:

```
Installing driver from C:\driver.sys
OK!
StartService failed: 1275
```

The error code is that of ERROR_DRIVER_BLOCKED. I tried to force Windows to allow me to install this after all by going into advanced startup and disabling signature enforcement, but the only effect was that Windows no longer gave me a separate OS window telling me it blocked driver installation.

I have tried the three methods described here, without any luck: https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-unsigned-drivers-windows10/

(However, I assume these are made for users hand-installing the drivers).

How can I tell Windows to allow me to programmatically install this unsigned driver?

Comment: you install driver ok already. for let unsigned driver run - `bcdedit /set testsigning on` and reboot

Comment: I still get the same error. As far as i know, there is no "test signing" on the driver, i think it is a plain windowxp driver without any signing. Here is a screenshot of the file details: http://s1.petterroea.com/serve?hash=1649fd93423bea0e9297

Comment: at first you confuse install and load driver. you install it ok. for load unsigned driver basically enough `bcdedit /set testsigning on` and reboot

Comment: I am still getting a 1275 on StartService after running the command you suggested and rebooting

Comment: but you view test mode label in bottom rigth on desktop ?

Comment: Yes, there is a test mode label in the bottom right of the desktop

Comment: are your system 64 bit and driver 32 ?

Comment: That is most likely correct, it's a windows xp embedded driver.

Comment: but your system 64 or 32 bit ? 32 bit driver can run only in 32 bit windows

Comment: That turned out to be the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The driver was 32-bit, the system was 64-bit. Using a 32-bit system solves this.